# Wix MsiPackage install if environmental variable exists

Tags: environment-variables, burn, wix3.11

In Wix 3.11 I am using burn to define a bundle and a chain of msi packages to install.

Something like:

```
<Chain>
  <!-- List of prerequisites: -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Prereq1"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Prereq2"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Prereq3"/>
  <!-- Our packages -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Package1"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Package2"/>
</Chain>
```

In Package1 I define the following:

```
<WixVariable Id="SrcFolder" Value="..\..\..\..\path-to-SrcFolder" />

<PackageGroup Id="Package1">
  <MsiPackage gd:LicenseId="Feature1" InstallCondition="Feature1" gd:Optional="no" SourceFile="!(wix.SrcFolder)\Feature1.msi"    Compressed="no" Name="packages\Feature1.msi">
    <MsiProperty Name='LICENSEFOLDER' Value='[LicenseFolder]'/>
    <MsiProperty Name='COMPANYNAME' Value='[Organization]'/>
    <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLFOLDER' Value='[InstallFolder]'/>
  </MsiPackage>
  <MsiPackage gd:LicenseId="Feature2" InstallCondition="Feature2" gd:Optional="yes" SourceFile="!(wix.SrcFolder)\Feature2.msi" Compressed="no" Name="packages\Feature2.msi">
  </MsiPackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

I would like to install my "Feature2" package only if there is a environmental variable defined in the installing machine, (ENV_VAR), and silently don't install the package it if that is not the case.

How could I do that?